# Whats the visual studio equivalent to eclipse alt + arrow Left

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

From Eclipse i'm confortable with

<kbd>F3</kbd> to enter a method and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd>

In visual studio (2010) its <kbd>F12</kbd> to enter the method, but how do i get back to the call, where i jumped in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to list all references, and the original method will be listed.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> will navigate backward, whilst <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> will navigate forward (in the context of where you were working in your code).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> will allow you to search for a method to navigate to.

Comment: Some freaking jackasses invented VS hotkeys. I think they are not humans and live in other planet.

Comment: It can take less time to use shortcuts than to use a mouse, assuming you know where to find the command you want in the context-driven menus. Plus... you don't have to use them if you don't want to :)

Comment: I want to use them. But they are not common. Every editor and web browser I know use Alt + Back Arror (instead of VS Studio and VS Code of course)

Answer (score 3):

In my VS Code V 1.20.1 the shortcut is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for backward.

For going forward is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

We can change these shortcuts just like in Eclipse by selecting the menu *File* -> *Preferences* -> *Keyboard shortcuts*, and type on the search field for `Go Back` or `Go Forward`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this on MacOS VS Code

- `^`+`-` to go backward.
- `^` + `shift` + `-` to go forward.

*Note that`^` is `control` on your keyboard.*

Full list of other mac keyboard shortcuts here: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf